# SQL UPDATE with CASE Statement Yields Incomplete Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following code is intended to update particular fields only when there's a value that relates to that field.

It returns an incomplete set of values.  Millions of rows are correct, but several thousand rows have values incorrectly set to NULL.

Is this is SQL limitation, or am I missing something?

```
UPDATE a
    SET ResultType1 = CASE WHEN b.[Type] = 'type1' THEN b.value END
       ,ResultType2 = CASE WHEN b.[Type] = 'type2' THEN b.value END
    FROM tableA AS a
    INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: After your edit, if values are set to NULL that simply means that b.value is also NULL. If you don't want that, you can add a where clause to your statement to filter those values out. `WHERE b.value IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Lieven: Not only because of that. The `ELSE NULL` that is always implied in `CASE` expressions will make many fields set to `NULL`, even if there are no Nulls in `b.value`

Comment: @Ypercube - Thinking about it, it makes sense but it's new to me, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> update particular fields only when there's a value that relates to that field

makes me think that you actually want to do this:

```
UPDATE a
  SET ResultType1 = CASE WHEN b.[Type] = 'type1' 
                           THEN b.value 
                         ELSE ResultType1 
                    END
    , ResultType2 = CASE WHEN b.[Type] = 'type2' 
                           THEN b.value 
                         ELSE ResultType2 
                    END
FROM tableA AS a
    INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

So, ResultType1/2 will be set to their existing values if the b.Type conditions are not met, INSTEAD of being set to NULL.

I am assuming that when you say "incomplete set of values", you mean that some are being set to NULL.

What is causing this behaviour is the implied `ELSE NULL` in `CASE` expressions.

---

If you actually want to update `ResultType1` and `ResultType2` with nulls, but only for those rows that are of different `'type'`, a slightly different query will do:

```
UPDATE a
  SET ResultType1 = CASE WHEN b.[Type] = 'type1' 
                           THEN b.value 
                         ELSE NULL                 --- this line can be removed
                    END
    , ResultType2 = CASE WHEN b.[Type] = 'type2' 
                           THEN b.value 
                         ELSE NULL                 --- this one, too
                    END
FROM tableA AS a
    INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE b.[Type] IN ('type1', 'type2')
```

Comment: I should have clarified - NULL can be a valid result.  In testing I'm getting ~25,000 rows with a different value (NULL or a smallint) to the source data compared to ~14 million that are correct.

Comment: I tried using a where clause to filter by type:  Across 3 types it works; Across 4 types it doesn't...!?!